# iterating through a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of list of characters `::[[Char]]`.
I need to iterate both over the list of strings and also over each character in each string.

Say, my list is present in this variable.

`let xs`

Please suggest an easy way to iterate.

Comment: We could give more specific advice if you also explained *what* you want to do while "iterating".

Answer (score 26):

If you want to apply a function `f` to every element of a list like this:

```
[a, b, c, d] → [f a, f b, f c, f d]
```

then `map f xs` does the trick. `map` turns a function on elements to a function on lists. So, we can nest it to operate on lists of lists: if `f` transforms `a`s into `b`s, `map (map f)` transforms `[[a]]`s into `[[b]]`s.

If you instead want to perform some IO action for every element of a list (which is more like traditional iteration), then you're probably looking for `forM_`:<sup>1</sup>

```
forM_ :: [a] -> (a -> IO b) -> IO ()
```

You give it a function, and it calls it with each element of the list in order. For instance, `forM_ xs putStrLn` is an IO action that will print out every string in `xs` on its own line. Here's an example of a more involved use of `forM_`:

```
main = do
  ...
  forM_ xs $ \s -> do
    putStrLn "Here's a string:"
    forM_ s print
    putStrLn "Now it's done."
```

If `xs` contains `["hello", "world"]`, then this will print out:

```
Here's a string:
'h'
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
Now it's done.
Here's a string:
'w'
'o'
'r'
'l'
'd'
Now it's done.
```

<sup>1</sup> `forM_` actually has a more general type, but the simpler version I've shown is more relevant here.

Comment: hi thanks for replying.actually i want to take every element out of the list and apply if-else consdition to that.so i want to store every element one by one in "let element" just like a for loop would do

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to iterate through a list performing IO while giving a name to each element.

Comment: I'm doing IO, your answer seems to help a lot, but I get a `Not in scope: ‘forM_’`. Any idea?

Comment: Sorted it out with `import Data.Foldable`. How come `forM_` takes the list as the first argument while `find`, `map` and all the others do it the other way round?

Answer (score 5):

Just that:

```
[c | x <- xs, c <- x]
```

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" way to iterate is actually *fold*. Anything you might ever want to do with a list can be done with a fold. Let's consider what you want to do. You're probably thinking of something like this:

```
for (row in xs):
  for (c in row):
    doSomething
```

The problem is, you're probably making use of mutable variables in `doSomething`. That's ok, we can deal with that. So suppose you have this.

```
def iter2d(xs):
  outerVar = outerInit
  for (row in xs):
    innerVar = innerInit(row)
    outerVar.adjust1(row)
    for (c in row):
      innerVar.adjust2(c)
      outerVar.adjust3(c, innerVar)
  return outerVar
```

Let's translate that to folds. And immutability.

```
iter2d :: [[Char]] -> Something
iter2d xs = foldl' outerStep outerInit xs
  where outerInit = ... -- same as outerInit above
        outerStep acc row = fst $ foldl' innerStep innerInit' row)
          where innerInit' = ((adjust1 acc row), innerInit row)
        innerInit row = ... -- same as innerInit above
        innerStep (outAcc, inAcc) c = (outAcc', inAcc')
          where inAcc' = adjust2 inAcc c
                outAcc' = adjust3 outAcc c inAcc'
```

Notice with immutability, we are forced to indicate that `outAc'` depends on `inAcc'`, rather than `inAcc`, meaning, the "state" of `innerVar` *after* it is updated.

Now you might say "wow that Haskell looks way ugly, why would I ever want to use Haskell". Yes, it does look ugly, but only because I tailored it to be a direct translation of imperative code. Once you get used to using *folds* instead of "iterating through a list", then you will find that folding is a very powerful technique that lets you do a lot of things in a more elegant way than for loops allow.

Comment: Note: `map` is a specialization of `fold`.

Comment: Good answer, but I also don't think your last paragraph makes much sense. There's many situations where a fold will do the job in a more straightforward manner than a for loop, sure, but the converse is also true, and for loops are a better tool in a lot of situations. The correct answer to the question "why would I ever want to use Haskell" is imo firstly that there's no need to distinguish between values and references in Haskell because everything is immutable, and secondly that the type theory allows you to get a big picture of what each function is doing w/o having to worry about...

Comment: ...side effects that aren't reflected accurately in the type of the function. Following this line of thought, the ultimate general purpose programming language would allow imperative constructs like loops and variable reassignment, while blocking mutation, while also capturing all reassignments in its type system so that if a block of code is reassigning a variable, this appears in the type of the block of code. The only remaining question is how to make such a language fast.

Answer (score 3):

```
map (map f) l
```

where `f :: Char -> Foo` is a function to apply to each `Char` and `l :: [[Char]]`
returns `l' :: [[Foo]]`