# Combining the results of double for loops in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function which generates a list of lists and then applies a function to each of those lists and combines the results into one big list. However I am getting an error and would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

The code currently looks like this:

```
solve_all :: [Constraint] -> Sol -> Sol -> CType -> [(Maybe Typing)]
solve_all c lam_env app_env t2= do 
  lst <- (simMatch c)
  forM lst $ \d -> do
    return $ case pleaseUnify d of  --ERROR HERE
      Right u -> Just substituteTyping u (lam_env .+. app_env, t2)
      Left _ -> Nothing
```

where:

`simMatch :: [Constraint] -> [[Constraint]]`

`pleaseUnify :: [Constraint] -> Either String Unifcation`

`substituteTyping :: Unifcation -> Typing -> Typing`

the error is pointing to the call **pleaseUnify d** saying I passed just one constraint instead of a list

```
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Constraint]’
                  with actual type ‘Constraint’
```

But I followed the answer which used forM in this question [iterating through a list in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014626/iterating-through-a-list-in-haskell)

and I am generating a list of lists from (simMatch c). So how come when I iterate I get only one constraint?

Comment: Note also that `forM lst (\d -> return ...)` is the same as `map (\d -> ...) lst` -- no monadiness necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well let's step through it and add comments about the types

```
solve_all :: [Constraint] -> Sol -> Sol -> CType -> [(Maybe Typing)]
solve_all c lam_env app_env t2 = do
```

At this point we're in the list monad (the return value is `[(Maybe Typing)]`).

```
lst <- (simMatch c :: [[Constraint]])
```

We bound a variable `lst` to simMatch in a list monad, so `lst :: [Constraint]`.

```
forM lst $ \d -> do
```

For each element of `lst` named `d`... so `d :: Constraint`.

```
return $ case pleaseUnify d of  --ERROR HERE
```

And we know `pleaseUnify :: [Constraint] -> who_cares` so we want `d :: [Constraint]` but have just above seen it must be a type `Constraint`.

Did you really mean to use the list monad and to name an intermediate value `lst`?  Perhaps you intend:

```
forM (simMatch c) $ \d ->
 return $ case pleaseUnify d of
  Right u -> Just (substituteTyping u (lam_env .+. app_env, t2)) -- Notice a fix here too
  Left _ -> Nothing
```